# Reverse number sign where sql

Tags: select, where-clause, sign

[Picture click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzXSP.png)

Dear all 
Please i want select sql Query to add - sign to numbers where invoiceType ='s'
how can i do this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Case condition to check if invoiceType ='s' then concentrate - sign else use normal invoiceamount.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN invoiceType ='s' THEN '-'||invoiceamount ELSE invoiceamount END FROM Invoice;
```

Or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN invoiceType ='s' THEN (invoiceamount * -1) ELSE invoiceamount END FROM Invoice;
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: Error converting data type from varchar to mumeric

Comment: SELECT        CASE WHEN invoiceType = 's' THEN (PerchaseSuppTotal * - 1) ELSE 'PerchaseSuppTotal ' END AS Expr1
FROM            TblInvoiceHeader

Comment: I tried with decimal data type also and its working.

CREATE TABLE invoice(Id integer, Name text, Amount decimal(5,2));
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES(1,'TYPE1',1.1);
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES(2,'TYPE2',1.2);
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES(3,'TYPE3',3.3);
Commit;

SELECT CASE WHEN id ='1 THEN (Amount * -1) ELSE Amount END FROM invoice;

Try this by creating new table.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: What was the issue ?